# Vimeo API replacing video file throws RequestException (timeout)

Tags: upload, timeout, vimeo, vimeo-api

I've been trying to replace source file by these docs - [Vimeo API Replace source file](https://developer.vimeo.com/api/upload/videos#replace-source-file).

I'm using Automatic (“pull”) uploads for upload and it works just fine. According to the docs, to replace a file, I should make `PUT` request to `/videos/{id}/files` and then proceed with `POST` to `/me/videos`, but every time `PUT` request fails and I get the same:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Vimeo\Exceptions\VimeoRequestException' with message 
'Unable to complete request.[Operation timed out after 30000 milliseconds with 0 bytes received]' 
in /home/<...>/vendor/vimeo/vimeo-api/src/Vimeo/Vimeo.php:154
```

`POST` and `PUT` request are fed with the same parameters. Maybe I should pass different type for `PUT` (`POST` gets `'type' => 'pull'`)?
Using Vimeo API PHP Lib v. 1.2
What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Definitely a bug in the API, it shouldn't timeout. We're on it. For direct support reach out to us at support@vimeo.com.

One thing that can help in the short term is to increase your PHP timeout using the curl option `CURLOPT_TIMEOUT` (this can be set on the php lib using `$lib->setCURLOptions([CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 60])` for 60 seconds).

Once this bug is fixed, it might not resolve the issue. There's a good chance that Vimeo's request to get metadata about the the pull url is timing out, which could be a slow link, or a problem with the upload servers. In either case I recommend reaching out directly for support.

For anyone in the future, if you see timeouts, feel free to reach out to support@vimeo.com for more direct assistance.